# Gramática/Concordância Verbal/Sujeito Simples - como concordar com este sujeito?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, concordância-verbal, sujeito

Estava fazendo exercícios ontem e fiquei com uma dúvida que não consigo encontrar em lugar nenhum. Na frase "Cerca de 1% de meus alunos que _____ ontem, _____ com um ponto a menos na próxima prova." é preciso empregar os verbos "faltar" (no passado) e "ficar" (no futuro) nas lacunas respectivamente.

---

Meu raciocínio até agora:

- o núcleo do sujeito é “alunos"
- a expressão “cerca de” não se caracteriza como expressão partitiva, pois para isso seria necessário haver um numeral acompanhando como nos exemplos “mais de um aluno tirou a nota máxima” ou “cerca de 5 alunos tiraram a nota máxima” e embora haja um número na frase ele fazer parte de uma expressão percentual.
- na frase a expressão percentual “1% de” age como expressão partitiva pois está acompanhada de uma preposição, neste caso, a preposição “de” e por conta disso o verbo precisa concordar com o número da expressão percentual, como nos exemplos “1% de meus alunos compareceu” ou “20% de minha turma faltaram”
- existe ainda o pronome “que” na frase, mas sua regra diz que se concorda com o antecedente, diria que é irrelevante neste caso.
- baseando-me nessa lógica diria que o primeiro verbo fica no singular (”faltou”) concordando com o número um da expressão percentual

o problema começa agora, não consigo dizer qual a lógica correta para o segundo verbo

- o segundo verbo ocorre logo depois de uma vírgula, poderíamos dizer que é uma nova oração, mas por contexto sabemos que o segundo verbo se refere ao mesmo sujeito do primeiro.
- porém não sei se repito a mesma lógica e concordo o segundo verbo com o numeral da expressão percentual, ficando no singular (ficará) ou se, por ser uma nova oração, concordo como núcleo do sujeito diretamente, ficando no plural (ficarão)

Também não sei dizer se meu raciocínio lógico está correto de maneira geral e se a concordância do primeiro verbo também está correta. Em fim agradeço qualquer ajuda ou feedback

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A frase original é: "Cerca de 1% de meus alunos que _____ ontem, _____ com um ponto a menos na próxima prova."

Nesta frase, o trecho "que _____ ontem" explica (fala sobre) o sujeito, podemos separar duas orações com o mesmo sujeito:

1. "Cerca de 1% de meus alunos _____ (faltar) ontem"
2. "Cerca de 1% de meus alunos _____ (ficar) com um ponto a menos na próxima prova."

As duas orações possuem o mesmo sujeito ("Cerca de 1% de meus alunos") que, por sua vez, é composto por uma expressão percentual ("1%") que age como expressão  partitiva de "meus alunos".

**ATENÇÃO**: A preposição empregada é "de", por isso, o verbo deve concordar exclusivamente com o numeral da expressão percentual!

- O numeral é menor que 2, logo, verbo concorda no singular.
- Como as duas orações possuem o mesmo sujeito os dois verbos concordam no singular.

Se juntarmos as duas orações, como feito na frase original, temos:

"Cerca de 1% de meus alunos que **FALTOU** ontem, **FICARÁ** com um ponto a menos na próxima prova."

Comment: Agora eu fiquei curioso. Onde você leu que o uso da preposição "de" obriga a concordância do verbo com a percentagem?

Comment: @Gui Imamura achei nestes vídeos: [vídeo1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4FEXeLH7s4), [vídeo2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yA4J24JT7ow&t=218s). Aparentemente não é uma regra tão comentada

Comment: Eu não usaria material no YouTube de (supostos) professores desconhecidos, cujas credenciais são desconhecidas, como fonte para fundamentar minha pesquisa. Vale lembrar também que `do`, `da`, `dos` e `das` são contrações da preposição `de` com um artigo definido, e equivalem à preposição `de`; ademais, nunca ouvi falar na regra citada nos vídeos, e elas conflitam com o que é dito nas fontes que eu apresentei. Imagino que esteja estudando para uma prova de concurso, e por isso peço que tome cuidado com a seleção de material com que vai estudar.

Comment: https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint51.php  Quando o sujeito é formado por uma expressão que indica porcentagem seguida de substantivo, o verbo deve concordar com o substantivo. **1% dos alunos faltaram à prova**

Comment: A regra que você mencionou não se aplica ao caso. Vamos recapitular, em caso de sujeito composto por expressão partitiva percentual + preposição "do(s)"/"da(s)" + substantivo o verbo pode concordar com o substantivo ou com o numeral: "1% dos **alunos** **faltaram**"/"**1%** dos alunos **faltou**". No caso da questão a preposição utilizada é **"de"** tornando inválido o uso desta regra. Outro ponto @Lambie, você está sendo bastante inconveniente ao dar downvote em nossas interações

Comment: @LucasA Me disculpa mas o exemplo dado no meu link e quase exatamente o seu: 1% dos alunos faltaram à prova.  Não é, semanticamente falando, o 1% que faltou. Foram os alunos que **faltaram**. Agora bem, pode existir o caso, também semanticamente falando, que falte o 1 %. Por exemplo:  "O um porcento que estava marcado na coluna, já não se ve".  É preciso levar em consideração o contexto e o sentido inteiro da frase. QED.

Comment: Otro ponto: Se eu pensar que uma resposta está errada, vou colocar um voto negativo.

Comment: Todos aqui temos o dever de votar negativamente em respostas que acha que ficou mal elaborada ou incorreta. Se sua resposta for boa, com o tempo ela deverá receber votos positivos e ter uma nota boa, apesar dos votos negativos. Além disso, quem votou negativamente fui eu, porque acredito que sua informação está incorreta e sua fonte não é confiável.

Comment: "As duas orações possuem o mesmo sujeito ("Cerca de 1% de meus alunos")" não é correto. A sujeito das duas frases é: *cerca de 1%*. Cerca de 1% **faltou.** comparado a: Cerca de 1% de meus alunos **faltaram**.

Comment: "o núcleo do sujeito é “alunos"" O sujeito não tem núcleo. O sujeito é: 1%.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que se pode usar o gerúndio como nas frases abaixo:

> [...] também devemos inserir a vírgula antes do gerúndio, quando ele é
> colocado após a oração central, equivalente a uma oração coordenada
> iniciada com “e” ou “e isso”. Confira abaixo novos exemplos:
>
> Em 2020, mudou-se para o Rio, **deixando** mais uma vez os estudos
> para trás;
> Ela reuniu todas as provas necessárias, **garantindo** a sua
> inocência;
> Ele contou toda a verdade, **acabando** com toda a farsa.

[gerúndio](https://www.clubedoportugues.com.br/virgula-antes-de-gerundio/)

Então na frase abaixo também se pode usar o gerúndio sem o que:

1. "Cerca de 1% de meus alunos **faltaram** ontem, **ficando** com um ponto a menos na próxima prova."

O antecedente de faltaram é alunos, no plural.
**OU**

2. Cerca de 1% de meus alunos que faltaram ontem ficarão com um ponto a menos na próxima prova. [**sem a virgula**]

- Cerca de 1% **faltou** ontem.
- Cerca de 1% de meus alunos **faltaram** ontem.

Vejam abaixo:

[Curso on-line do *Só Português*](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint51.php)

> 5. Quando o sujeito é formado por uma expressão que indica porcentagem
>    seguida de substantivo, o verbo deve concordar com o substantivo.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> 25% do orçamento do país deve destinar-se à Educação.
> 85% dos
> entrevistados não aprovam a administração do prefeito.
> 1% do
> eleitorado aceita a mudança.
> **1% dos alunos faltaram à prova**.

Exemplos encontrados na Internet, todos no plural:

**Cerca de 10% dos alunos** do ensino médio **voltam** às salas de aula em Bento Gonçalves

[semanario](https://jornalsemanario.com.br/cerca-de-10-dos-alunos-do-ensino-medio-voltam-as-salas-de-aula-em-bento-goncalves/)

**Cerca de 10% dos alunos voltaram** às aulas presenciais na rede estadual em Alegrete

[Alegrete](https://www.alegretetudo.com.br/cerca-de-10-dos-alunos-voltaram-as-aulas-presenciais-na-rede-estadual-em-alegrete/)

De acordo com a secretária de Educação Cláudia Favero, **cerca de 10% dos pais ainda não foram** até as escolas para retirar as atividades.
[Xanxerê](https://xanxere.sc.gov.br/noticia-615617/)

Gramática, FONTE: O Mundo da Educação

-**O verbo concorda com o sujeito quando esse é um número expresso em porcentagem, sem especificação.**
Ex: ***Um por cento  não compareceu à aula**.*
***Noventa por cento  não compareceram à aula**.*

-**Quando o sujeito vem especificado o verbo concorda com esse**:
Ex: ***Dois por cento dos alunos não compareceram à aula.***
***Dez por cento do alunado está em dia com as mensalidades***.
[Mundo da Educação](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/concordancia-verbal.htm)

Comment: Obrigado por ter respondido, talvez eu não tenha deixado claro a questão da flexão do verbo, mas o gerúndio não é uma opção válida. A principal dúvida seria mesmo se os verbos ficam no singular ("faltou" e "ficará") ou no plural ("faltaram" e "ficarão") ou alguma variação das duas.

Comment: O gerúndio é válido e segue a mesma estrutura que postei nos dos exemplos. Só que é preciso tira o "que" Teria de ser: "Cerca de 1% de meus alunos que faltaram ontem ficarão com um ponto a menos na próxima prova." [sem a virgula]

Comment: Ou seja, faltaram e ficarão sem virgula OU faltaram e ficando com virgula.

Comment: Na pergunta é mencionado que trata-se de um exercício proposto. Neste caso é intuitivo tratar a estrutura frasal como fixa, e não se remover vírgulas e/ou palavras para manter correção gramatical.

Comment: @GuiImamura E no "exercício" proposto foi preciso corregir a frase, obviamente.

Comment: https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint51.php 5) Quando o sujeito é formado por uma expressão que indica porcentagem seguida de substantivo, o verbo deve concordar com o substantivo.

Exemplos:

25% do orçamento do país deve destinar-se à Educação.
85% dos entrevistados não aprovam a administração do prefeito.
1% do eleitorado aceita a mudança.
**1% dos alunos faltaram à prova**.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, nas duas orações os verbos devem concordar com o mesmo exato sujeito; no entanto, em casos onde há porcentagem e substantivo, a concordância verbal pode ser feita de acordo com qualquer um dos dois:

> Cerca de 1% dos meus alunos que **faltou** ontem, **ficou** com um ponto a menos na próxima prova.

> Cerca de 1% dos meus alunos que **faltaram** ontem, **ficaram** com um ponto a menos na próxima prova.

Ambos os casos acima estão corretos.

Fontes:
1: [https://www.tjsc.jus.br/web/(...)/como-concordar-frases-com-percentual-ou-porcentual-](https://www.tjsc.jus.br/web/servidor/dicas-de-portugues/-/asset_publisher/0rjJEBzj2Oes/content/como-concordar-frases-com-percentual-ou-porcentual-)
2: https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/concordancia-verbal/amp/

Comment: No primeiro link: Somente 1% dos candidatos **conseguem** passar nos exames (concorda com candidatos). porque concorda com o antecedente candidatos e não 1%....igual que na frase postada na pergunta. O antecedente é alunos. Será que você não leu bem os exemplos??

Comment: Todas a frases mostram que o verbo concorda com o antecedente. população seria no singular. Veja bem os exemplos no seu própio link.

Comment: A orientação mais atual é fazer a concordância com o substantivo próximo, ou seja, usar o verbo no singular quando o substantivo está no singular; verbo no plural quando o substantivo está no plural: O seu link. A sua resposta está errada.

Comment: "Sim, nas duas orações os verbos devem concordar com o mesmo exato sujeito;" Não, devem concordar com o subtantivo (antecedente)  mas próximo. Como diz o seu link.

Comment: @Lambie se você reler com atenção, verá que é dito que: 1. o aluno pode optar pela forma que quiser; 2. existe uma *orientação* quanto a isso, mas no final da página é dito que o aluno pode optar "não usar a fórmula acima". Há exemplos para todos os casos, e nenhum deles é dado como incorreto. Portanto, sugiro que releia atentamente as fontes citadas e peço que retire seu voto negativo.

Comment: @Gui Imamura Eu consegui resolver a questão, vou colocar a resposta aqui, você usou o raciocínio correto porém a frase original usa a preposição "de" e não "dos", por conta disso a regra muda e diz que é obrigatório concordar com o numeral da expressão percentual